# Candidate Key найти

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть взаимоотношение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как найти Candidate Key здесь? Уверен, что здесь не один. И покажите способ нахождения

Я считаю, что DBA, BAD - это candidate key

Comment: Ключи, как и функциональные зависимости выявляются на основании анализа предметной области. Не понятно, что вы собираетесь получить. Из части известных функциональных зависимостей остальные? Тогда разве что транзитивные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) BA->C
2) BA->E (транзитивность)
3) BA->DB (транзитивность)
4) BA->D (проективность)
5) BA->B (проективность)
6) BA->A (транзитивность через 4)
```

Итого, всё зависит от BA. Получается, что BA - ключ.

Comment: Самое интересное, что еще Candidate Key является C и E, потому что от этих элементов можно "ссылаться" на другие элементы. Спасибо тебе за помощь) Ясно и понятно